# installing mod_ssl amazon linux

Tags: centos, ssl, amazon-web-services

I'm simply trying to install mod_ssl on a CentOS server. Doing a straightforward sudo yum install mod_ssl would return an error:

```
Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.25-1.0.amzn1.x86_64
Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.25-1.0.amzn1.x86_64
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I tried to remove httpd-tools by: `sudo yum remove httpd-tools-2.2.25-1.0.amzn1.x86_64` but no luck.

I also did `sudo yum -v remove httpd-tools-2.2.25-1.0.amzn1.x86_64` and outputs this:

```
Yum Version: 3.2.29
rpmdb time: 0.000
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: httpd-tools-2.2.25-1.0.amzn1.x86_64
Setting up Package Sacks
amzn-main                                                  |  2.1 kB    00:00
amzn-updates                                               |  2.3 kB    00:00
pkgsack time: 0.330
Package(s) httpd-tools-2.2.25-1.0.amzn1.x86_64 available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal
```

And, when doing `sudo yum search mod_ssl` will output this:
[image]

None of what I tried to do works. Anything that I am missing?

Comment: CentOS or Amazon Linux, which is it? I've never had to manually install `mod_ssl` on Amazon Linux, it comes automatically with the `http` / `http24` packages.

Comment: @ceejayoz - How did you install your LAMP stack?

Comment: `yum install httpd24 php54 mysql55-server` plus a variety of modules that fit my requirements. Again, this is Amazon Linux, which is similar but not the same as CentOS.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it with `yum install mod24_ssl`.